# how to change a variable to a different value without using many if - statements python

Tags: python, set

Let's say I have a variable called temperature. And I want its value to be different according to the conditions. Normally I would do something like this:

```
temperature = None
country = input()
if country == 'USA' :
    temperature = 10
elif country == 'Spain':
    temperature = 20
elif country == 'Peru':
    temperature = 30
#and so on
```

But that takes forever, if I have many values. I have a feeling I need to use sets but I haven't begun using them (and dictionaries). However if that is the way to do it, I'd like to know.

Comment: You can create a table of instructions and conditions. It all depends on what exactly you need to do when the condition is met.

Comment: can you give an example of what the condition might be? you need to find a pattern in order to do it dynamically.

Comment: please add the condittions in your sample code

Comment: i did so in the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
country = input()
cond = {'USA': 10, 'Spain': 20, 'Peru': 30 } 
temperature = cond.get( country, None )
```

Comment: exactly but could i ask why in cond.get(country , None) you added None. I mean it should work without shouldnt it?

Comment: Yes, it will work, but if the object is not in the dictionary, an exception will be thrown

Comment: The `None` in `cond.get(country, None)` is the default value (the value `cond.get` will return in the case that `country` is not found in the dictionary). If you do not specify a default value and `country` is not found in the dictionary, "an exception will be thrown".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-line solution that you might found better than the other one :

```py
temperature = {"usa": 10, "spain":20, "peru":30}[input("Enter a country name : ").lower()]
```

So I directly used the dictionary without storing it in a varibale because it's a short dictionary, but if you have a long one then it's much better to use a variable instead.
The country names are written in lower case so they match the user input that i also transformed to lower case with the `.lower()`.