# Simplify and Improve for Multi-If-Statement

Tags: python, performance, dna-sequence

I am trying to randomly generate multiple short 5 base-pair DNA sequences. Among them, I want to pick the sequences that meet the following conditions:

1. If the first letter is A then the last letter cannot be T
2. If the first letter is T then the last letter cannot be A
3. If the first letter is C then the last letter cannot be G
4. If the first letter is G then the last letter cannot be C

The same requirements are repeated for the second and the second to the last letters.

I am currently using a very long If-Statement to make the first-last letter work, but I was wondering if there is a simple way to achieve the same result so I don't have to repeat the long statement for making the second-second-to-the-last letter work? If so, how should I change the code? Thank you.

```
import itertools

a = "ATCG"

for output in itertools.product(a, repeat=5):
    if((output[0] == 'A') and (output[4] != 'T')) or ((output[0] == 'T') and (output[4] != 'A')) or ((output[0] == 'C') and (output[4] != 'G')) or ((output[0] == 'G') and (output[4] != "C")):
        list = "".join(output)
        print(list)

'''
```

Comment: use 2 pointer method to start from first and last and check if they matched condition ?

Comment: you might also see your solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65540712/how-to-change-a-variable-to-a-different-value-without-using-many-if-statements but @Mad Physicist s answer is perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dictionary containing the forbidden opposite:

```
forbidden = {
    'A': 'T',
    'T': 'A',
    'C': 'G',
    'G': 'C',
}
```

Now you can check that the character at index `-1 - i` is not the forbidden opposite of the one at `i` by doing a simple lookup. The trick is to loop only over the first half of the string:

```
def check(s):
    for i in range(len(s) // 2):
        if s[-1 - i] == forbidden[s[i]]:
            return False
    return True
```

Incidentally, this will work correctly on both even and odd string lengths.

```
for sequence in map(''.join, itertools.product(forbidden.keys(), repeat=5)):
    if check(sequence):
        print(sequence)
```

All that being as it may, it's a bit inefficient to generate a bunch of extra sequences when you only want ones matching a specific pattern. The pattern is that the first half of your string is constrained to 4 options, while the second half is to 3. You can therefore generate only matching patterns with something like this:

```
def generate(n=5):
    first = random.choices('ATCG', k=(n + 1) // 2)
    second = random.choices('ATC', k = n // 2)
    second = ['G' if s == forbidden[f] else s for f, s in zip(first, second)]
    return ''.join(first + second[::-1])
```

Given that only one character is forbidden, you can generate any three characters for the second half, and replace forbidden ones with the missing. The second half then gets reversed because of how you actually want to compare the halves.

Comment: About `generate`: clearly it doesn't build forbidden pairs, but  are the pairs it does build unbiased?

Comment: @KellyBundy. I am pretty sure that this follows the uniform distribution given by the filtered `product`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?
You can define regular expression to filter your outputs.

To learn more about regular expression: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
import itertools
import re

a = "ATCG"

case1 = ["(^[A].{3}[^T]$)",
         "(^[T].{3}[^A]$)",
         "(^[C].{3}[^G]$)",
         "(^[G].{3}[^C]$)"]

case2 = ["(^.[A].[^T].$)",
         "(^.[T].[^A].$)",
         "(^.[C].[^G].$)",
         "(^.[G].[^C].$)"]

case1_filter = '|'.join(case1)
case2_filter = '|'.join(case2)

for output in itertools.product(a, repeat=5):
    sequence = ''.join(output)
    if re.match(case1_filter, sequence) and re.match(case2_filter, sequence):
        print(''.join(output))
```

Comment: This is for the 1st and last letter, but what about "The same requirements are repeated for the second and the second to the last letters"?

Comment: oh I missed that part, let me fix that!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use sets:

```
disallowed = [{'A', 'T'},
              {'C', 'G'}]

for output in itertools.product(a, repeat=5):
    first_last = {output[0], output[4]}
    second_fourth = {output[1], output[3]}
    pairs = (first_last, second_fourth)

    if all(pair not in disallowed for pair in pairs):
        sequence = "".join(output)
        print(sequence)
```

We're using the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function which takes a Python sequence and will return `True` if all items in the sequence evaluate to `True`. This means it only evaluates enough to determine it: once one value evaluates `False` it stops comparing because the result will always then be `False`.

`pairs` is just a tuple of the two sets. This makes it easy to iterate over the two sets. Otherwise we would just have to write the comparison twice. I'd rather do it in a loop and write the comparison once.

The sequence we pass to the `all` function is each of the two pairs, and we check to see whether it is not in `disallowed`. If both pairs are not in `disallowed` then `all` returns `True`.

Comment: I believe you need frozenset rather than sets since Python does not allow set of sets (e.g "TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'").

Comment: @DarrylG I've replaced `disallowed` with a list of sets as the test for `disjoint` would need to check all subsets anyway, so a linear search of the list doesn't affect performance.

Comment: Get "TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'" on line `if {first_last, second_forth}.isdisjoint(disallowed):`

Comment: @DarrylG apologies, I have been careless. Thank you for your attentiveness.

Comment: Looks good so will upvote (but I would not call a variable `list` due to the built-in function).

Comment: @PeterWood, would you mind explaining the rational behind the code a little bit more? I am learning Python and don't fully understand the "pairs =" statement, is it a dictionary in a set? and why the IF statement also includes the disallowed operation for first/second letter being T or G and the last/fourth being A or C?

Comment: @DarrylG I was just modifying OP's code, but will fix

Comment: @indigo I've added some explanation. Let me know if it's inadequate.

Comment: @PeterWood Thank you. Another question: the current coding is able to rule out the condition for [0] = 'A' then [4] != 'T' or [1] ='C' then [3] != 'G', but if I want to include the condition for [0] = 'T' then [4] != 'A', or [1] = 'G' then [3] != 'C', do I just expend the elements in the 'disallowed' dict?

Comment: @indigo no, that's already covered. You're just interested in whether both first and last are `'A'` and `'C'`. We make a set out of the first and last values and then ask is this set `{'A', 'C'}`. It doesn't matter whether `'A'` was first or last, we're comparing the set, not the order.